# Is there fb.ui dialog option for "Share this Link" functionality?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We've tried the ShareThis plug in with our Wordpress site and like the ability to choose the destination (own wall, friend's wall, in a group and on your page). ShareThis opens a new tab to do the dialog and we're also not crazy about using a third party anyway. We really prefer the way the fb.ui dialogs work. Is there a method that gives those destination options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is nothing specific for a Link, but the FB.ui('feed') can be used to post to Wall or PostToTimeline in the new way of things.

Sample code:

```
FB.ui(
{
  method: 'feed',                
  app_id: settings.ShareAppId,
  name: settings.ShareAppName,
  link: settings.ShareLink,
  picture: settings.SharePicture,
  caption: settings.ShareCaption,
  description: settings.ShareDescription,
  message: settings.ShareMessage
},
  function(response) {                
    // Deal with callback.                                          
  }
);
```

More on this call at [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Comment: Thanks Shreeni, the 'feed' method is what we're using at present. Was hoping there's an alternative that allows setting the destination.